# Copy right policies of Math.SE

Tags: discussion, copyright

I have a small issue to be answered. What are the boundaries and scope for copyrights at Math.SE ? . To explain further, suppose I have described a new idea in the question, what if someone copies and use the idea ?.

Similar situation, suppose if I present some new way of solving a problem and posted the answer, and others have used it. What is the situation then ? .

I am not after recognition and fame, but there will be some body who feel bad doing so. So I asked this question for general purpose. Please do clarify my doubts.

Thank you.

Comment: This is explained in section 3 of http://stackexchange.com/legal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Much of the comments to [this answer at meta.MO](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/951/copyrights-at-mo) will apply. In particular, let me plagiarize myself:

> 1. In terms of "copyright" (as stated in your question title): the answer is either *not safe at all* or *completely safe* depending on your interpretation. As discussed in the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#editing), by posting on [MSE] you agree to license what you wrote under a CC license, which means that anyone can legally copy and republish what is written, provided he gives proper attribution.
> 2. In terms of "academic priority", it is generally understood that MSE is a public forum with timestamps. So it would be very foolish indeed for someone to plagiarize what you wrote here.

See also [the link to "attribution required"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) and to ["cc-wiki"](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) at the bottom of every page, as well as [the stackexchange legal page](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: What happens when the users have a proxy name ? , should one indicate those Proxy names ?.

Comment: IIUC legally [copyright doesn't apply to ideas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright#Scope) but only to fixed expressions of ideas.

I don't think posting on MSE is considered publication, it is more like an informal discussion by people interested in math. I don't think people would consider it [plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagirism) if someone uses a similar solution in a paper. The issue regrading MO is quite different IMHO.

Comment: @Kaveh What do you think is different on MO?

Comment: @Bill, it is way more likely for a researcher to check MO to see if there is a similar result than MSE, MSE is not a standard place for checking if a result is already known. If I write a post in my publicly readable blog about something does it mean I will be cited for the it? For almost all blogs the answer is no. There are established venues for publication and MSE doesn't seem to be one so far. On the other hand researchers have been citing MO posts for more than a year in their papers. This is the difference I see between MO and MSE:

Comment: 1) is it expected from a mathematician to check MSE? 2) is MSE accepted as a publication venue among the mathematicians? I would check papers in standard journals, arXiv, and probably MO posts for what I am working on. I might check with some experts working in the area to make sure it is not already proven well-known folklore result among the experts. Checking MO is similar to these, probably more to the later. That is what the community expects from an author.

Comment: I wouldn't check MSE/math forums/blogs/... Just posting an idea somewhere on the Internet is not sufficient to be able to claim credit for it, particularly when it is not a standard reviewed publication venue and AFAIU it is expected that results should appear in such venues. People may cite private communications or other resources but it is unlikely that anyone would be considered to have conducted plagiarism if they are not cited. (I will post a question on [academia.se] to see if there is disagreement with I have stated above.)

Comment: @Kaveh SE content is licensed by [CC BY-SA 2.5.](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) This is completely independent of MO.

Comment: @Bill, as I said above, *ideas are not copyrightable*! and the question is asking about ideas. So CC BY-SA 2.5 is irrelevant (e.g. if I restate the idea in my own words). The comments about MO was in reply to your question in your comment above and the original one was because Willie referred  to it in his answer. It seems to me that the OP is confusing copyright with credit for ideas.

Comment: @Kaveh I was interested in understanding why you think there is some difference between MO and MSE regarding such matters, because I don't agree with that. If someone wants to claim priority by publishing a proof of a theorem here, then, IMO, that is no different from doing the same on MO.

Comment: @Bill, and I explained above the reason I disagree with that.

Comment: @Kaveh There are plenty of examples throughout history where the first published proofs of theorems were in obscure places, e.g. Kronecker's proof of an important theorem at the basis of ideal theory - which Dedekind later rediscovered - his "Prague theorem", a generalization of Gauss' Lemma. MO is no different than MSE in this regard.

Comment: @Kaveh Suppose I discovered a short elementary proof of FLT and I posted it first to MSE. Do you really think that would not establish priority?

Comment: @Bill, and it is not clear that in such cases the credit should be given to the prior one. Also note that those cases are quite old and the people involved in such cases are generally established mathematicians.

Comment: @Bill, no, as long as it has not passed peer-review no one is going to cite it or take it seriously. If it is correct and important enough that you would like to be credited for it you are expected to go through publication process which includes peer-review. If I write a blog post solving P vs. NP is the person who will solve it need to give credit to me? Obviously not. As I understand credit is due only when you are aware of the solution and its correctness.

Comment: @Kaveh But that's not the point we're discussing. Rather, we're discussing if MO is any different than MSE in this regard.

Comment: @Bill, it is the point. What I am saying is that AFAIU it is not expected to check MSE to make sure a result is original and even if someone is aware doesn't mean that the solution is correct. This is even more so in the case of ideas for solutions in place of rigorous solutions. MO differs from MSE on both.

Comment: @Kaveh I strongly disagree. I suppose we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Bill: More elementary than the one I discovered recently? "* (1) If FLT was not true then that other proof that was given to it would be false. (2) The other proof holds. $\Rightarrow$: (3) FLT is true.*"

Comment: @Kaveh, you write "as long as it has not passed peer-review no one is going to cite it or take it seriously".  That is simply not true.  If the posted proof is discovered to be _correct_, people _will_ take it seriously, regardless of whether it has been formally peer reviewed.  (I say that as the author of a paper that cites [_an offhand comment of Bill Thurston on sci.math_](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/gina/Thurston-hexahedra.html) as an indisputable primary source.)

Comment: @JeffE, OK, I have exaggerated.

Comment: Unless I am reading things incorrectly, @BillDubuque is claiming that the MSE poster has priority, while Kaveh is claiming *not* that this doesn't matter in a *legal sense*, but that it doesn't matter *for any practical purpose*? Something which come out of MSE will not be groundbreaking within itself (there just isn't enough space in a post!), although it may lead to something groundbreaking. If I post on MSE "I am thinking of using $X$ in order to prove FLT" and then someone else uses $X$ to prove FLT and publishes first then...so what? They win. One cannot copyright ideas.

Comment: (Case in point: [Serre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_conjecture) cannot claim to have proven FLT!)

Comment: @user1729: in your example there is no difference between first publication in MSE or first publication in Annals of Mathematics. An offhand remark stating that "X maybe of use in proving FLT" is not a proof, no matter how prestigious the venue of publication. In other words, _if it ain't plagiarism when published elsewhere, it ain't plagiarism when published here_; and conversely, _if it is plagiarism when published elsewhere, it is also plagiarism when published here_.

Comment: Much of @Kaveh's points must be read in the context of his assertion "I don't think posting on MSE is considered publication, it is more like an informal discussion by people interested in math." If one accepts that as a given (I certainly don't; I believe that there can be novel contributions posted in answers here), then the issue of academic priority is moot, as nothing discussed here (by that assertion) is novel or interesting.

Comment: That's my point (although I am not sure if I was making a point, or just trying to get clarification from Bill and  @Kaveh). MSE is a breeding ground for ideas which may lead to theorems, but publishable results (and ones which someone might accidentally plagiarise) will rarely (if ever!) appear here. Remember, the example the OP uses is describing a new *idea* here.

Comment: @WillieWong: However, if you have an example of a new, publishable result which someone might want to plagiarise which appeared here first then I will happily retract my previous post, and I would be interested in reading such an example!

Comment: @user1729: Extant? no. Unlikely? probably. Impossible? I think (hope) not.

Comment: @user1729 But the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111164/in-which-ordered-fields-does-absolute-convergence-imply-convergence which is original and may or may not be entirely new, is certainly new enough that neither an expert in the field (Pete Clark) nor an amateur generalist (yours truly) have seen before. And it has certainly been "plagiarized" with permission from the OP.

Comment: @Bill, the replies over [academia.se] to my [question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2057/1089) are more in line with your view and I understood that my objection about being confident about correctness of the content of a citation doesn't hold (since one does not need to take responsibility for the correctness of the content of the citations).

Comment: Dear Kaveh, One's obligation as an academic is to be honest and as well-informed as possible.  If you know of prior work relevant to what you are doing, or that you work builds on, you have to cite it.  You should endeavour to find about such work, within reason.  If you later learn about such prior work after you announce or publish your own work, you have to retrospectively acknowledge it (although it is fine to mention that your own work was done indendently).  As others have said, no-one expects you to scour the internet looking for previous work.  But if you become aware of such work, ...

Comment: ... on MathSE, MO, someone's blog, or any other forum, you have to take it into account; you can't pretend it doesn't exist.  It's no different to learning about prior work published in an obscure journal.   (Note, by the way, that if you weren't aware of prior work, by definition you are not guilty of plagiarizing it; but you will lose priority claims that you may have been making prior to learning about it.)  Regards,

Comment: @Matt, thank you. My two concerns (confidence in the correctness and the amount of time needed to check if the result is new) are [addressed](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2057/163).

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks for the link to your interesting related [question on Academia.SE.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2057/1089) I encourage those interested in this topic to read the answers there.

Comment: I really don't understand this talk about "it is not expected to check M.SE, but I would check standard journals". It is absolutely impossible for anyone to check all standard journals, unless "standard" is conveniently defined as the journals in my office. There is no way that an obscure publication would *not* be viewed as priority even though it would not be necessarily be "expected" that you checked that particular obscure place.